# Dedicated physical network interface to containers in an isolated way?

Tags: docker

I haven't found what I want to do though it seems basic architecture.

On my host I have multiple physical interfaces and `docker0` by default (that is connected to which interface?!)

- One interface `eth0` is for the host and default network of Docker containers.
- My other interface `enp0s20f0u1` should be used by only few selected containers in a isolated way. That means nothing else is allowed to connect to this interface.

I guess I need to create a Docker network but I have no way to tell it to use only one interface and nothing else.

**Example:**
- container c1: run without anything => should be connected to `docker0` and anything else
- container c2: run with `--net=none` => no network access, completely isolated
- container c3: run with `--network=myspecificnetwork` => connected to `enp0s20f0u1` and nothing else, isolated

How to create the `myspecificnetwork` Docker network to use only the interface `enp0s20f0u1`? And how to block everything else from using this interface?

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Comment: not solved, I gave up. Will check again later if I need.

Comment: Ok please edit the Q&A when you have new information

Comment: I will for sure ;)

Comment: Thanks. Please let me know then I will reopen the Q&A.